# How can I access sensor information using Flutter on iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I am trying to access the inbuilt sensor values on top of just accelerator and gyroscope in iOS in my flutter project.

I only found this tutorial for android https://github.com/itzmeanjan/sensorz
but I could not find any equivalent for iOS.

I've seen the pub.dev sensors method but that only allows for 2 sensors to be utilized, I am wondering if I could use any more with iOS

Comment: Which sensors do you need to access?

Comment: Preferably as many as I can access @creativecreatorormaybenot